# How do you turn on "Dark Mode" in OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos

Has anyone figured out how to enable Dark Mode yet? I've been looking around for a while and haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Comment: In the betas, you can find dark menu bar and dock as a check mark in the general settings in Preference Pane. Once we have a public release, this can be reopened and answered definitively.

Comment: try this https://github.com/nirbhayg/Flick/releases

Answer (score 9):

System Preferences > General > Use dark menu bar and Dock

[image]

Answer (score -2):

[image: Gif on How to enable dark mode in OSX Yosemite]

[Source of Turn on Dark Mode in OS X Yosemite Gif](http://www.osxiosexpert.com/how-enable-dark-mode-osx-10-10-yosemite/)

Comment: This GIF is outdated, the release version looks like dwightk's screenshot.

Comment: (it's actually patrix's screenshot)